# How to track single user behavior from a website

Tags: web-scraping, google-analytics, tracking

I need to Track single user behavior on my website, such as if the user **Click** on a button, his **location**, **time spending** in the product page ..., i use google analytics to track the Traffic but the problem is that i cant get every user and his behavior, it gives me just the total page view, total sessions...etc

Is there is another option or tools to do that ?

Comment: Most users wouldn't take kindly to you gathering location data when they're on your site

Comment: However, if you're already using GA, according to [this site](https://nancy-rubin.com/2019/05/31/how-to-track-user-location-in-google-analytics), in Google Analytics, "The locations report can be found under Demographics in the Audience section"

Comment: yes but is there is a method allows me to Track every user behavior not all the users, and gives me a table of  users and there behaviors